# ClassName::class vs 'ClassName' in PHP

Tags: php, performance, class, optimization

In one of my projects we are having a function which validates objects like:

```
if( true == valObj( $someObj, 'SomeClass' ) ) {
    //Do some work;
}
```

While using this I thought this can be written like:

```
if( true == valObj( $someObj, SomeClass::class ) ) {
    //Do some work;
}
```

Now I just want to know which approach is better and why?
Or are they same?

Comment: Well for starters, for the second one the class definition must actually have been loaded, whereas with the first one you can pass any string you like ... (whether that would actually make much of a difference depends on what your validation function actually does.)

Answer (score 2):

The `::class` notation is generally better as it allows for easier usage finding and thereby refactoring: If you use an IDE like PHPStorm you can easily rename a class, and it will find and update all usages of `OldClassName::class` to `NewClassname::class`. This is not the case for the hardcoded string variant.

If you use namespaces using this notation can also result in less inline characters.

If you are running a PHP version that supports this notation, use it :)

Comment: I didn't say anything about readability, that is highly subjective. You can still use the FQCN if that is your preference: `\App\Models\User::class`.

Comment: Sorry didn't meant that you said it, bad wording ;)

Answer (score 1):

`SomeClass::class` returns the full namespace including the class name.
Whilst if you use the string notation you have to add the namepace (if any) yourself.

Edit:

It doesn't matter which notation you choose, although I personally prefer the string notation as it shows you directly what namespace the class is in while scrolling through code.

Answer (score 0):

from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)
The special `::class` constant are available as of PHP 5.5.0, and allows for fully qualified class name resolution at compile, this is useful for namespaced classes.

```
<?php
namespace foo {
    class bar {
    }

    echo bar::class; // foo\bar
}
?>
```

This is also a magic constant. have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php